OOM error when using only one of two loss functions but successfully trains when using both losses
I am training a network that uses two losses - Cross Entropy Loss (ce_loss) and Triplet Loss (tr_loss). I am trying to do an ablation study to investigate the effect of both losses. Using both losses or only ce_loss works well with my current batch size; however, when I remove the ce_loss calculation and only use tr_loss, Out of Memory error stops the training.
Code snippet for using both losses. I comment out one and amend the loss formula for the ablation study.
outputs = model(...)

ce_loss = ce_criterion(outputs, labels)
tr_loss = tr_criterion(outputs[anchor_idx], 
                       outputs[positive_idx], 
                       outputs[negatives_idx])

loss = ce_loss + tr_loss
loss.backward()

Am I possibly missing something here? I assumed using only one loss should use less memory than both.
